Problem deploying Safe mastercode contract in BSC
I'm helping a friend recover some assets sent in the wrong network. The target address is a Safe multisig, but it does not have an implementation (mastercode) contract behind it. That'd need to be deployed.
I've checked the official instructions (Case 4) but those assume that the default deployer contract has not yet sent transactions. In this case, it has, so I can't use the hardcoded deployment transaction.
The weird thing is that the proxy contract and factory contract already exist - just the masternode is missing. How could I get the right (version 1.1.1) masternode deployed? It should be in the default address.

I just wanted to express my deepest gratitude for the time and effort you've dedicated to assisting me with the BSC Safe contract issue. Your research and guidance have been invaluable, and I truly appreciate your willingness to help. Thank you for your support and for sharing your expertise. It's people like you who make the blockchain community a better place.
